# Setup store email address to send to more than one address in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration

In admin panel **Stores > Configuration > General > Store Email Addresses** I can add one email to the 'Custom Email 1' section. I'd like to **add two email addresses to the field rather than one**, so for example the email is sent to me@mydomain.com and me2@mydomain.com.

How can I achieve this please in **Magento 2**?